# Emacs org-mode: org to html conversion -- semi-complicated literal tags

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I include `~` in between literal tags so that the end result is `<code>~/.emacs</code>`? Obviously, `~~/.emacs~` won't work...

Similarly, how can I make something italic within literal tags so that the result is `<code>something something <i>italicize</i></code>`? Obviously, `~something something /italicize/~` won't work...

(I am using the default functions used with `org-publish-project` for the conversion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the `~` character in monospaced formatting, you could use *code* markup: `=~/.emacs=`. The HTML output appears to be the same for me. I had inconsistent results with including `~` in the *verbatim* markup, e.g. `~/~/.emacs~` seems to work, but your example doesn't.

According to the org-mode manual, [Emphasis and monospace section](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Structural-markup-elements):

> Text in the code and verbatim string is not processed for Org-mode specific syntax; it is exported verbatim.

So, to get the formatting you desire in the literal tags, you need to use HTML and escape it:

```
~something something @<i>italicize@</i>~
```

See [Quoting HTML tags](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Quoting-HTML-tags) for more details.